# HTML Output in Pyscript

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I was experimenting in Pyscript and I tried to print an HTML table, but it didn't work. It seems to delete the tags and mantain just the plain text.

Why is that? I tried to search online, but being a new technology i didn't find much.

This is my code:

```py
<py-script>
print("<table>")
for i in range (2):
    print("<tr>")
    for j in range (2):
        print("<td>test</td>")
    print("</tr>")
print("</table>")
</py-script>
```

And this is the output I get:
[image: pyscript test output]

I tried to replace the `print()` method with the `pyscript.write()` method, but it didn't work too.

Comment: `write()` replaces all content in tag - so first create string with table and later use `write()`

Comment: @furas tried, but it doesn't work. it just prints "test", but thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I have reproduced your problem. The current version of Pyscript is doing something strange with strings containing HTML tags. Pyscript is stripping out the HTML tags even from raw strings. I have verified this with the Chrome debugger. Note: do not use `print()` to output HTML. Use the normal DOM `document` API calls. However, that is not working either today. Something has been broken.

Answer (score 2):

I dig in source code [pyscript.py](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/pyscriptjs/src/pyscript.py)
and at this moment works for me only code similar to JavaScript

For example this adds `<h1>Hello</h1>`

```
<div id="output"></div>

<py-script>

element = document.createElement('h1')
element.innerText = "Hello"
document.getElementById("output").append(element)

</py-script>
```

---

Full working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PyScript Demo</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />-->
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="output"></div>

<py-script>

element = document.createElement('h1')
element.innerText = "Hello"
document.getElementById("output").append(element)

</py-script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT:**

After digging in source code I found that `pyscript.js` runs function `htmlDecode()` which removes all tags from code in `<py-script>` (and probably it also removes tags when you load code from file) and this makes problem.

See Pyscript issue: [[BUG] print() doesn't output HTML tags. · Issue #347 · pyscript/pyscript](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/347)

Some workaround is to use some replacement - ie. `{{ }}` instead of `< >` in code - and later use code to replace it back to `< >`

```py
print( "{{h1}}Hello{{/h1}}".replace("{{", "<").replace("}}", ">") )
```

or more universal - using function for this

```py
def HTML(text):
    return text.replace("{{", "<").replace("}}", ">")

print( HTML("{{h1}}Hello{{/h1}}") )

pyscript.write(some_id, HTML("{{h1}}Hello{{/h1}}") )

document.getElementById(some_id).innerHTML = HTML("{{h1}}Hello{{/h1}}")
```

---

Sometimes problem can be also `pyscript.css` which redefines some items and ie. `<h1>` looks like normal text.

One solution is to remove `pyscript.css`.

Other solution is to use classes from `pyscript.css` like in [examples/index.html](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/pyscriptjs/examples/index.html)

```
<h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">Hello World</h1>
```

which means

```
print( HTML('{{h1 class="text-4xl font-bold"}}Hello{{/h1}}') )
```